# Primary School Project - Timing gate

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I'd like to apologise in advance if this has been asked before, but I have searched repeatedly and haven't found anything that helps.  I'd also like to point out that I am a complete beginner to code, please forgive me if this turns out to be simple or a silly question.

I am trying to build a simple timing gate that I can teach to a group of year 6 pupils (age 10/11).  We are using python 3 and a raspberry pi to create the gates.  The timing gate will need to display the time it takes a CO2 powered car to travel between two points.  This one of our first projects.

Their idea is that it will consist of 2 motion sensors set a known distance apart.

When the first sensor is triggered  - start time

When the second sensor is triggered - end time

print (end - start)

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import time
from time import sleep


pir = MotionSensor(19)
pir2 = MotionSensor(4)


while True:
    if pir.motion_detected:
        start = time.time()


    if pir2.motion_detected:
        end = time.time()

        print(end - start)
```

The motion sensors detect the movement and print numbers to the screen, but they are long strings of numbers that we can't interpret.

We would like to ask:

Is there a simple way of getting the time to display in seconds (to 3dp)?

Answer (score 2):

The function `time.time()` returns you a unix-timestamp, that is the number of seconds passed since 01.01.1970, as a floating point number. Being a number in the order of 1.5 billion it doesn't give you much insight per se, but if you use it to compute time differences, it works perfectly fine. I experienced the accuracy to be dependent on the system I used (Windows vs Ubuntu), but it was never worse than the millisecond accuracy that you require.